# Improvements for the AmazonS3 presignedURL in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, pre-signed-url

I'm looking for some improvements and recommendations for the AmazonS3 presignedURL with Cognito. I've noticed that sometimes the expiration date expires sooner than set. This causes the error "Unexpected response code 400".

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Amazon S3
private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3() {
    return amazonS3;
}

public void setAmazonS3(AmazonS3 amazonS3) {
    this.amazonS3 = amazonS3;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    // AWS
    RunnableAWSS3 runnableAWSS3 = new RunnableAWSS3(activity);
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnableAWSS3);
    thread.start();
    thread.join();

    // Getting the JSON data stored in S3 bucket
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, runnableAWSS3.getPresignedURL(), null, response -> {
        ...
    });
}
```

**RunnableAWSS3.java**

```
public class RunnableAWSS3 implements Runnable {

private final ActivityMain activityMain;

private URL presignedURL;

public RunnableAWSS3(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    activityMain = (ActivityMain) activity;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (activityMain.getAmazonS3() == null) {
        // AWS
        // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                activityMain,
                "us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                Regions.US_EAST_1
        );
        activityMain.setAmazonS3(new AmazonS3Client(cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider, Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)));
    }

    // Set the presigned URL to expire after twelve hours.
    presignedURL = activityMain.getAmazonS3().generatePresignedUrl(
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 43200000));
}

public String getPresignedURL() {
    return presignedURL.toString();
}
}
```

Sometimes I'm getting an error E/Volley: [200] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for ... when getting the presigned URL.

I would appreciate some recommendations for the improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Presigned URLs have restricted expiration time based on how they were signed. For temporary credentials like with cognito it will have a much smaller expiration time than if it was signed using IAM credentials. Your presigned urls expire as soon as the session for the cognito user expires.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/